# How to pass username and password automatically in scp module?

Tags: perl, copy

```
I am copying the files from one host to another using:
 Net:scp::Except;
 here is my script
```

use strict;
use Net::SCP::Expect;

print "enter user name\n";
my $username = <>;

print "enter password\n";
my $pass = <>;

print "enter host name\n";
my $host = <>;

my $src_path = "/";
my $dst_path = "/";

my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(user=>$username, password=>$pass,     auto_yes=> '1');
$scpe->scp($host.":".$src_path, $dst_path);

```
getting error like bad password
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to give user name and password as a input in scp module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023429/how-to-give-user-name-and-password-as-a-input-in-scp-module)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times (you can edit or comment your original question)

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving those variables from STDIN and they all include a trailing `\n`. You'll want to `chomp` them before use:

```
chomp ($username,$pass,$host);
my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(user=>$username, password=>$pass, auto_yes=> '1'); 
$scpe->scp($host.":".$src_path, $dst_path);
```

Net::SCP::Expect runs the scp program with a command line stitched together from your parameters. So, without chomping it will effectively be truncated to `scp yourusername`